# Windows 10 - how to launch rate and review popup/view?

Tags: windows-10, uwp

Is there still possible on Universal Windows Platform (UWP) to launch 'rate and review' app windows?

On Win8 the line below worked fine, but it doesn't anymore on Win10

> await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new
>   Uri("ms-windows-store:reviewapp?appid=" + CurrentApp.AppId));

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the package family name of the APP to launch the rate and review section.

```
   await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(string.Format("ms-windows-store:REVIEW?PFN={0}", Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id.FamilyName)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can still use the `Launcher` class for that purpose:

```cs
public async Task OpenStore()
{
    const string productId = "YOUR PRODUCT ID";
    var uri = new Uri("ms-windows-store://review/?ProductId=" + productId);
    await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
}
```

Possible launch options for the *Windows Store* are defined [here (Launch the Windows Store app)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt228343.aspx).

The required values (e.g. Product ID) can be found *in the Windows Dev Center dashboard on the App identity page in the App management section for each app.*

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned earlier you could launch the Windows Store app to ask for a review:

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(string.Format("ms-windows-store:REVIEW?PFN={0}", Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id.FamilyName)));
```

But since Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (10.0; Build 14393) it’s possible to **show a rating dialog inside your app**. I think it’s a nice feature that seems to have gone on the radar. This code does this, and return true if the user reviewed or rated the app:

```
public async Task<bool> ShowRatingReviewDialog()
{
    StoreSendRequestResult result = await StoreRequestHelper.SendRequestAsync(
        StoreContext.GetDefault(), 16, String.Empty);

    if (result.ExtendedError == null)
    {
        JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(result.Response);
        if (jsonObject.SelectToken("status").ToString() == "success")
        {
            // The customer rated or reviewed the app.
            return true;
        }
    }

    // There was an error with the request, or the customer chose not to
    // rate or review the app.
    return false;
}
```

The code was copied from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/request-ratings-and-reviews